# Why does my jQuery UI Accordion Not Display Accurate Dimensions

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

http://mindfulintegrations.com/signiacapital/accordian.php

I am using Jquery Accordion UI and if you look at the above page you can see it doesn't display the text correctly - the buttons are in odd places and the width of the text isn't spanning the white text block fully.

What I want is for the accordion to be under the flash image and expand when the other buttons are clicked, and have it expand the "white background" as necessary to fit the expanded text.

I think this might have to do with the container div having a static height set - but when I try giving it a large height it still does not display properly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick look indicates that this in your CSS may be the culprit:

```
.processAccord {
position:relative;
}
```

Why is it relative?  It doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: I am really new to CSS - your comment makes sense. I want it to appear in the boundaries of that white box - if its not relative, then it just seems to span the entire DIV container (751px width). How do I position it, then? I know, this is an idiotic noob question but I would sincerely appreciate the training/help.

Comment: I kept troubleshooting with firebug and you were right - I had to alter the whole layout of the site, but I achieved some level of success. Decided jQuery UI Tabs was a better fit for the space, too.

Really appreciate your help.